# Gradle project sync failed in using a library from GitHub

Tags: android, github, gradle

I'm trying to use [SwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)  *library from GitHub* but i getting this error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0
```

i tried everything including:

- removed `@aar`
- search and add library from `ProjectStructure -> app -> Dependencies`

and so on..

first i though maybe the problem is this library, but i tried to use [this one](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) but still getting that error.. if anybody can give me a clue i'll be so appreciate. *and could u explain what's difference between* `compile '` *and* `compile "` *i tried both*

*this is my * `build.gradle' file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.drgnme.listhamrah"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.github.roojin:persian-calendar-view:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'    
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
}
```

Comment: Post your gradle file.

Comment: Make sure that you have good internet connection to download all the files required for that library. In some cases , if the port is not open the android studio fail to sync the imported library. I tried with your mentioned library and it works fine for me..!

Comment: @stephingeorge did it work for u really? yeah i did what u said, i even try this > `Invalidate Caches/Restart` but still failed :((

Comment: Ya it works for me fine. Are you using any Proxy in the Settings - Files > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Http Proxy

Comment: @Abhi i added this file

Comment: @stephingeorge No i'am not. i even used `VPN` and still the same result

Comment: Sorry i didn't get the actual problem . So you may try to download the executable jar for the required library  and put it in the libs folder and then add the dependancy.. !

Answer (score 0):

Simply try like this:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/study_level_list"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="85dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

in Java File;

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)rootView. findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
```

and bind your listview like this;

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Refresh the data
            // Calls setRefreshing(false) when it is finish
              mAdapter = new MyAdapter(studypojo.getStudylevelList());
              list_view.setAdapter(mAdapter);
              mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The author does not states it, but after checking the project files, it seems he's deploying the artifact to central (AKA maven central). So, add mavenCentral() to your repository list and you should get the artifact. Alternatively, you could use the jitpack repository.